# How to call javascript function on click of column in fusion chart

Tags: javascript, html

there are 2 div in html and i want to load div2 on click of div1.

whenever div2 loads a back button also load there to go to div1.

how to do it in html?

```
<td background="images/bgTd.gif" class="MenuTxt">Trends</td>
  <td width="17">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
      <img src="images/back.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; right: 0;"/>
      <a class="aclass"onclick="plottrend1()">
        <img src="images/back.png" width="17" height="22"style="position: absolute; top: 30; right: 70;"/>
      </a>
  </td>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, editing your HTML to make it readable has discovered that it's invalid.  You'll want to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Call Java script function in fusion chart.. 
Using the following in your set tag

```
 link="JavaScript:yourfunctionname()"
```

Comment: <set label="Others" value="'+other_chart_tat+'" color="5B9A00" link="JavaScript:checkChart(\'Others\',\'income\');"/>